# C# Office interop Excel - out of boundary

Tags: c#, excel, exception, multidimensional-array

I have a program that I need to maintain ( was not written by me) 
What the actual function is doing is that it gets an excel file from the internet and then convert it to html (I don't even know why) then it tries to save it into a new csv file...

Long story short, my problem in the whole code resides in these 2 parts

```
xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xl.Visible = false;
//p_sUBKPath is the path of the HTML file that has the converted excel file
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(p_sUBKPath,     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); 

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws =  (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = ws.UsedRange;
object[,] values = (object[,])range.Value2;
```

The code has an if statement that try to ensure that every values from the first row in the html matches values required

```
if (Convert.ToString(values[1, 1]).ToUpper().Trim() == "DOMAIN NAME" && values[1, 2]).ToUpper().Trim() == "SHORT NAME" && values[1,3]).ToUpper().Trim() == "LONG NAME" )
{
     //do something
}
```

The if statement is returning true and jumping to else statement, after few debugging and trying some lines of code it turned out that values[1,2] and values[1,3] are returning out of array boundary error.
and the value of values[1,1] is the whole row which contains DOMAIN NAME, SHORT NAME, AND LONG NAME, so even this statement returns flase

```
if (Convert.ToString(values[1, 1]).ToUpper().Trim() == "DOMAIN NAME")
{
     //do something
}
```

Any idea what is happening in the code?

Comment: Does the worksheet look correct in Excel?

Comment: Actually, they have updated the source of the Excel, so it was an Excel file, but now it is a CSV file, but when I ran the code the CSV file was loaded to the HTML, so I supposed that I can apply the same code to the new source..

Comment: If `values[1, 1]` is the whole row, then obviously Excel did not open the CSV file correctly, but put all content into the first column. Try setting the `Format` parameter of the `Open` method.

Comment: The csv file is passed to to excel as HTML file, so in the first line of code p_sUBKPath is the html file that has the csv data.

Comment: They are semicolon seperated, where the old file was comma seperated